# Access user-specific localized resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, localization

I'm building a .NET Web App, with localized strings being given by the Multilingual App Toolkit. It generates a static class with properties that have names as defined in the resources file. It looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
/// </summary>
// This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
// class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
// To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
// with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
internal class Strings {

    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

    private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    internal Strings() {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("FaqBot.Resources.Strings", typeof(Strings).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
    ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
        get {
            return resourceCulture;
        }
        set {
            resourceCulture = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Good Morning.
    /// </summary>
    internal static string Greeting {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Greeting", resourceCulture);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to Welcome.
    /// </summary>
    internal static string Welcome {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("Welcome", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code where I access the strings, I can set the culture, and subsequent accesses to the string properties return the correctly localized strings.

Now, my Web App has the option to let the user choose their language, and I have a mechanism for storing this preference. However, since the Strings file is static, if one user changes the language, the subsequent strings for the other users are getting changed as well.
One way to bypass this would be to set the culture explicitly before every string access, but this would lead to race conditions and ugly code.

How can I let each user get responses in their preferred language without setting the culture explicitly before each string access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do so, would be creating a new `HttpModule` :

```
public class LocalizationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // check if user is authenticated
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            /* 
               Your code to read user's culture name from the profile and
               put it in "lang" variable
            */
            var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
    }
}
```

and get it run through registering it in the `web.config` file :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="LocalizationModule " type="LocalizationModule"/> <!-- put the full namespace and class name in type attribute eg. MyApp.MyNamespace.LocalizationModule -->
     </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```